# Bag Of Visual Words Implementation in Python is giving terrible accuracy

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am trying to implement myself a bag of words classifier to classify a dataset I have. To be certain that my implementation is correct, I used just two classes from the Caltech dataset (http://www.vision.caltech.edu/Image_Datasets/Caltech101/) to test my implementation: elephant and electric guitar. As they are totally different visually, I believe that a correct implementation of Bag Of Visual Words (BOVW) classification could classify these images accurately.

From my understanding (please correct me if I am wrong), the correct BOVW classification happens in three steps:

1. Detect SIFT 128-Dimensional descriptors from training images and clusterize them with k-means.
2. Test the training and testing images SIFT descriptors in the k-means classifier (trained in step 1) and make a histogram of classification results.
3. Use these histograms as feature vectors for SVM classification

As I explained before, I tried to solve a very easy problem of classifying two very distinct classes. I am reading the training and testing files from a text file, I use the training images SIFT descriptors to train a k-means classifier, use the training and testing images to get the histogram of classifications and finally use them as feature vectors for classification.

The source code of my solution follows:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

#this function will get SIFT descriptors from training images and 
#train a k-means classifier    
def read_and_clusterize(file_images, num_cluster):

    sift_keypoints = []

    with open(file_images) as f:
        images_names = f.readlines()
        images_names = [a.strip() for a in images_names]

        for line in images_names:
        print(line)
        #read image
        image = cv2.imread(line,1)
        # Convert them to grayscale
        image =cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        # SIFT extraction
        sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
        kp, descriptors = sift.detectAndCompute(image,None)
        #append the descriptors to a list of descriptors
        sift_keypoints.append(descriptors)

    sift_keypoints=np.asarray(sift_keypoints)
    sift_keypoints=np.concatenate(sift_keypoints, axis=0)
    #with the descriptors detected, lets clusterize them
    print("Training kmeans")    
    kmeans = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=num_cluster, random_state=0).fit(sift_keypoints)
    #return the learned model
    return kmeans

#with the k-means model found, this code generates the feature vectors 
#by building an histogram of classified keypoints in the kmeans classifier 
def calculate_centroids_histogram(file_images, model):

    feature_vectors=[]
    class_vectors=[]

    with open(file_images) as f:
        images_names = f.readlines()
        images_names = [a.strip() for a in images_names]

        for line in images_names:
        print(line)
        #read image
        image = cv2.imread(line,1)
        #Convert them to grayscale
        image =cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        #SIFT extraction
        sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
        kp, descriptors = sift.detectAndCompute(image,None)
        #classification of all descriptors in the model
        predict_kmeans=model.predict(descriptors)
        #calculates the histogram
        hist, bin_edges=np.histogram(predict_kmeans)
        #histogram is the feature vector
        feature_vectors.append(hist)
        #define the class of the image (elephant or electric guitar)
        class_sample=define_class(line)
        class_vectors.append(class_sample)

    feature_vectors=np.asarray(feature_vectors)
    class_vectors=np.asarray(class_vectors)
    #return vectors and classes we want to classify
    return class_vectors, feature_vectors


def define_class(img_patchname):

    #print(img_patchname)
    print(img_patchname.split('/')[4])

    if img_patchname.split('/')[4]=="electric_guitar":
        class_image=0

    if img_patchname.split('/')[4]=="elephant":
    class_image=1

    return class_image

def main(train_images_list, test_images_list, num_clusters):
    #step 1: read and detect SURF keypoints over the input image (train images) and clusterize them via k-means 
    print("Step 1: Calculating Kmeans classifier")
    model= bovw.read_and_clusterize(train_images_list, num_clusters)

    print("Step 2: Extracting histograms of training and testing images")
    print("Training")
    [train_class,train_featvec]=bovw.calculate_centroids_histogram(train_images_list,model)
    print("Testing")
    [test_class,test_featvec]=bovw.calculate_centroids_histogram(test_images_list,model)

    #vamos usar os vetores de treino para treinar o classificador
    print("Step 3: Training the SVM classifier")
    clf = svm.SVC()
    clf.fit(train_featvec, train_class)

    print("Step 4: Testing the SVM classifier")  
    predict=clf.predict(test_featvec)

    score=accuracy_score(np.asarray(test_class), predict)

    file_object  = open("results.txt", "a")
    file_object.write("%f\n" % score)
    file_object.close()

    print("Accuracy:" +str(score))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main("train.txt", "test.txt", 1000)
    main("train.txt", "test.txt", 2000)
    main("train.txt", "test.txt", 3000)
    main("train.txt", "test.txt", 4000)
    main("train.txt", "test.txt", 5000)
```

As you can see, I tried to vary a lot the number of clusters in the kmeans classifier. However, no matter what I try, the accuracy is always 53.62%, which is terrible, considering that the images classes are quite diferent.

So, is there any problem with my understanding or implementation of BOVW? What I've mistaken here?

Answer (score 4):

The solution is simpler than I thought.

In this line:

```
  hist, bin_edges=np.histogram(predict_kmeans)
```

The number of bins is the standard number of bins from numpy (I belive it is 10). By doing this:

```
   hist, bin_edges=np.histogram(predict_kmeans, bins=num_clusters)
```

The accuracy increased from the 53.62% I reported to 78.26% using 1000 clusters and, therefore 1000 dimensional vectors.

Comment: Just fyi: In https://github.com/shackenberg/Minimal-Bag-of-Visual-Words-Image-Classifier/blob/master/learn.py#L130 they use `sqrt` of the number of sift features as number of clusters.

Comment: @Framester with your suggestion, I achieved 84.05% accuracy using an RBF kernel SVM classifier with grid search over cost and gamma parameters. Thank you so much for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are creating clusters and histograms for each image. But in order to make it work you have to aggregate the sift features for all images and then clusters theses and use these common clusters to create the histogram. Check out also https://github.com/shackenberg/Minimal-Bag-of-Visual-Words-Image-Classifier

Comment: I am extracting SIFT descriptors from all training images and aggregating them in the same matrix. This matrix is used in the k-means clustering. Do you recommend me to also consider SIFT descriptors from testing images in the k-means clustering?

Comment: > I am extracting SIFT descriptors from all training images and aggregating them in the same matrix.
Ah, than I overlooked that.

> Do you recommend me to also consider SIFT descriptors from testing images in the k-means clustering?
No, that would not be sound and cause overfitting, because one would use (implicitly) information from the test set.

Comment: what do you mean by aggregating sift features? I am already using all SIFT features from all training images to cluster them in the k-means. In the code you suggested me to check the author says "Aggregating the histograms of the visual words for each of the traning images" and it is quite ambiguous to me. We don't aggregate the histograms in my understanding, what we do is considering all points from the same image (aggregate its points) to calculate its histogram. What I am not understanding here? thanks.

Comment: I think it is meant, that the histogram is calculated for each image and all these histograms are "aggregated" or better "collected" in one 'datastructure' and used as features for training.